# Write & save xlsx file located in blob storage via Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, xlsx

I have a xlsx file in a azure bolb storage. Now, I want to access this xlsx file to do some edits and save it back. I have tried it locally. But I don't know how to do this when the file is in blob storage. The following code are used to do it in locally . Note: I don't want to save the first to my local drive and then edit. I want to directly edit it and save it via powershell.

````
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jubaiaral\OneDrive - BMW\Documents\Book1.xlsx")
$sheet = $workbook.worksheets | where {$_.name -eq 'Sheet1'}
..................my edits come here...................
$workbook.Save()
$excel.Quit()```
Thanks in advance!
````

Answer (score 0):

> I want to directly edit it and save it via powershell.

I dont think you can directly update the file and save it using powershell. You can

- Copy the file
- Do the work
- Copy it back to the storage .

If you want to do this in place you use SPARK ( Azure Synapse / Azure databricks )

This may be helpful : https://community.databricks.com/s/feed/0D53f00001HKHeOCAX